# PHP script store image to folder and path to MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, storing-data

I have a form in html which runs a php script whitch inserts text fields into a MySQL database. I use this database for creating user profiles but in the profiles i need also sound, video and pictures. Is there any script which creates a folder on the hardrive with the name i insert from the form and store the selected files in this folder and inserts the file path into the MySQL database?

Also i need to display them into a search result page and from the result page if i select a user i need to redirect me to a page wich displays the selected record whith it's own photos, sound, video and text as a profile page or something like this.

here is the form:

```
<form action="process.php" method="post" >
    <label>Όνομα:</label> <input type="text" name="Fname" /><br/><br/>
    <label>Επώνυμο:</label> <input type="text" name="Sname" /><br/><br/>
    <label>Είδος:</label> <input type="text" name="Genre" /><br/><br/>
    <label>Είδικότητα:</label> <input type="text" name="Specialty" /><br/><br/>
    <label>Βιογραφικό:</label> <input type="text" name="Bio" /><br/><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Καταχώρηση"/>
</form>
```

and here is the script:

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","root");
if (!$con)
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("fasma", $con);

$sql="INSERT INTO artists2 (Fname, Sname, Genre, Specialty, Bio)
VALUES
('$_POST[Fname]','$_POST[Sname]','$_POST[Genre]','$_POST[Specialty]','$_POST[Bio]')";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
{
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "Registration Successful";

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: and what will happen if i send request with POST data: Fname='); DROP TABLE artists2; ?

Comment: it will insert the name you send to a new entry on the database.

Comment: Yo dawg! We heard you like SQL injection so we got Bobby Tables on your site so you can drop tables while you drop tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When it comes to finding PHP functions, you should always check the PHP manual: http://php.net/manual/en/index.php

It has great documentation on PHP's functions, including how to create folders/directories on your server.

As for uploading and storing files, it's easier than you thnk:
First, in your form, you need input fields of the type "file". For example:

```
<label>Photo:</label> <input type="file" name="uploadImage" id="file" /><br/><br/>
```

Once the form is submitted to process.php, this will upload the file to a temporary location on your server. In process.php, the file and the temporary location can be accessed like so:

```
$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
```

You can then copy the file to any location on your server that you like. And since you are the one who decides where the file will be copied to, you can insert the file path into your database as you see fit.

For more information, check out: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Comment: Thank you my friend! :) Another question, how to run the php script when i hit the button from the form, without redirecting me to the php page and showing me the "Registration Successful". ?

Comment: Unless you're making the request via AJAX, it will redirect you to that page. What you can do is have the php script re-direct the user to another page of your liking once the login has been successful. Look up the header() function in the PHP manual link that I posted.

Comment: Side Note: You should sanitize your form input before making it part of a database query.Right now you don't, and it could cause an attacker to mess with your database with a technique known as SQL Injection. More information here: http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Comment: I don't care too much about SQL injection because this would not upload on the web. I will run it on my pc ONLY. :) but thank you for the information! I will have it in my mind for another project.

Comment: Also i read the article from the w3schools but i can't understand how to enclude the script given from w3schools into my script i gave you before. can you help me with the code please? I haven't slept for 3 days and my mind is a mess. 
I just nedd to write on the script, to make a dir on the root folder  which will name it with the Fname and the Sname and inside this folder i want all the images, videos, mp3's to be putted in.
And finally store the paths of the files into the MySQL database in the new record i created with the form i gave youm so i can access them fow showing.